# Disable a 'click' function when the user scrolls beyond a certain point

Tags: jquery

I am really struggling with this so I hope someone can help! I have the following code that swaps the items from being white to black by toggling the class.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cd-nav-trigger').click( function() {
$("#headerlogo").toggleClass("headerlogoblack");
} );
});
</script>
```

But I need this to only work if the user hasn't scrolled beyond 80 pixels, once they do, this function should no longer work. How do I achieve this please - similar examples on StackOverflow I just can not get to work with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a conditional to check the scroll position of `window` using [`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$('.cd-nav-trigger').click(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 81) {
    $("#headerlogo").toggleClass("headerlogoblack");
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you, works exactly as I needed it to. I did have to make one small amendment and add  $(document).ready(function(){  before your code, without doing that it would not work. This is being used in a Wordpress site if that makes any difference.